# API случай создания заказа пользователя

Tags: moysklad-pos-api

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо устанавливать "пустое место"

**owner - Ссылка на Владельца (Сотрудника) в формате Метаданных**
для этого нужен код в формате метаданных.
Имеется ли таковой?

Заказчику нужно именно пустое поле при создании заказа по API

Answer (score 2):

На официальном сайте есть документация по работе с [заказами покупателя](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9). В частности, если нужно отвязать owner, то можно при обновлении заказа покупателя указать owner со значением null. Подробно можно прочитать [тут](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#header-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-null). 
Пример

```
    curl -X PUT \
  https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customerorder/e055feda-4bbb-11e9-7a33-90410000006e \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic ENTER_YOUR' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: ENTER_YOUR' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "meta": {
        "href": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customerorder/e055feda-4bbb-11e9-7a33-90410000006e",
        "metadataHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customerorder/metadata",
        "type": "customerorder",
        "mediaType": "application/json",
        "uuidHref": "https://online.moysklad.ru/app/#customerorder/edit?id=e055feda-4bbb-11e9-7a33-90410000006e"
    },
    "owner": null
}'
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.